# How to fix error: The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: c#, ajax, sharepoint

We have a Sharepoint solution that uses AJAX. The button that triggers this is inside an update panel.

One of the things that we do is generate a MS Word document, that is then opened on the client so that it can be printed.

The code that sends the document to the client looks like this:

```
    void OpenFileInWord(byte[] data)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
        Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

The error that we are getting is:

`Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '<?mso-application pr'.`

We could save the document in Sharepoint first, and then open it from Sharepoint, but we would prefer not to do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The action that causes this code to execute MUST be a postback event, and not an AJAX call.

This is due to the nature of the way AJAX requests are processed.

Comment: Arghh, I had a button in an Update Panel in .NET. Pulled it out and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 34):

If you have the button inside updatepanel this maybe causing this, if don´t want to move it, just add a trigger for the button on the updatepanel,  a postback trigger.

Comment: Nice answer. My problem is got solved. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: My problem also is got solved, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

Keep your button outside the update panel. Then it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Set your button to cause full postback like this:

```
 <Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="PrintButton" />
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding script manager in your page load, like this:

```
((ScriptManager)Master.FindControl("ScriptManager1")).RegisterPostBackControl(btnExport);
```

Answer (score 1):

On your button click, redirect to another page that can stream any files that you might want to do this type of thing with. We use a document.aspx page in many of our sites and then pass a document id via querystring and stream the file from there.

In your example, you're basically trying to change the headers for a page that's already  been displayed which isn't allowed

Comment: `In your example, you're basically trying to change the headers for a page that's already been displayed which isn't allowed`. It is allowed, there's no need of a separate page for it.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was duplicate control ID's in template columns of a grid view. Once I renamed the controls to be unique grid-wide, the problem disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

I had an asp:Table control inside an asp:UpdatePanel control.
The table had some static rows and some rows were added during
a Postback event.

This error occurred because rows and columns of the table did not
have static IDs. So IDs changed at each postback and this cause
problems with restoring ViewState for the table.

To stop this error I disabled ViewState for the table: EnableViewState="false"

`<asp:Table ID="PageContentTable" runat="server" ... EnableViewState="false">`

Answer (score 0):

I removed the update panel around the button and it worked fine.

Comment: There is already a solution to this question which does not require any significant architectural changes to the application.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this for a few hours. Doing an ajax request within my WebForms `Code-Behind` file wasn't working & using an `UpdatePanel` resulted in that annoying error and I wasn't able to find a solution. Finally I found a solution that works!

- Somewhere in your project create an `.ashx` (Generic Handler) file. I created mine within a top level services folder so: `Services\EventsHandler.ashx`. When you do this you should end up with both an `.ashx` & `.ashx.cs` file.
- Inside the `ashx.cs` file you'll find a `ProcessRequest` method where you can put all of your code.
- You can call this method doing something similar to the following in your javascript file:

  ```
  $('#MyButton').click(function () {
      var zipCode = $('#FBZipBox').val();

      $.getJSON('/Services/EventsHandler.ashx?zip=' + zipCode, function (data) {
          var items = [];
          $.each(data.Results, function (key, item) {
          items.push('<span>item.Date</span>');
      });
  }).complete(function () {
      // More Logic
  });
  return false;});
  ```
- Within your `ashx.cs` file you can access the query parameters using:

  **var category = context.Request.QueryString["zipCode"];**
- You can then return the result using:

  **context.Response.Write(yourResponseString);**