# Response.Redirect in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

`Response.Redirect()` no longer working when upgrade the application to ASP.NET 4.0

- `Response.Redirect()` is used inside Update panel
- and we using the `AjaxToolKit 4.0`

it gives me the error:

> Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the
>       server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is 
>       modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is 
>       enabled.
>       Details: Error parsing near

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UpdatePanel doesn't support resonse.redirect asynchronousely. You should either completely postback the page or avoid using it.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1539851.aspx/1?Response+Redirect+not+working+on+an+UpdatePanel+if+redirecting+to+a+ClickOnce+application+in+some+cases+

http://forums.asp.net/t/1392827.aspx

[How to fix error: The message received from the server could not be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554728/the-message-received-from-the-server-could-not-be-parsed-common-causes-for-this)

Answer (score 3):

you have to do this

```
string redirectURL=(a proper url goes here)

string script = "window.location='" + redirectURL + "';";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "RedirectTo", script, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `True` as the second argument like this:

```
Response.Redirect("http://...", true);
```

Comment: now i get `Error: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514.`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue...  You need to replace your version of the AjaxControlToolkit with the latest version built specifically for 4.0.  It's a drop-in replacement, so it should affect anything else.[See Ajaxcontroltoolkit on codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Comment: i had replaced the dll but the same error here, can you guide me what i'm missing

Comment: @mBotros - Interesting...  Can you post your code?  We do redirects from async postbacks all the time in 4.0 w/ the latest AjaxControlToolkit - no problem.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue. Resolved by using PostBackTrigger control

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="UploadButton" />
</Triggers>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to redirect to another page with an async request.

You can overload the `Response.Redirect` function and set it to false.

```
Response.Redirect("URL",false);
```

> by setting it to false, it will terminate your current request and go to the next request.

I am 100% sure it will work for you.

Comment: i got , `Error: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514.`

Answer (score 1):

You should try doing it like this:

```
Response.Redirect("URL", false);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

You will be redirected and no error will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I have been choking with this problem for entire days without advancing.
Update contents of a panel, AsyncPostBackTrigger if the caller is outside updatePanel. If you want to redirect, you add it as PostBackTrigger.
Both things on updatepanel using:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server" OnClick="link_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="link" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My issue had to do with the controls being generated dinamically inside a custom control due a listview.

The solution:

> ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(myRedirectButton);

In my case, i was using a listview on the item data bound, so i got the control using:

```
Control myRedirectButton = ListViewDataItem.GetControl("controlId")
```

Keep in mind the diference between Async and not ones. It was the main point that i didnt notice it until very far.

Answer (score 0):

This is also happening in one of our projects that we migrated from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.0

The problem only occurs **when compression is enabled**. We had a custom Response Filter in the `Global.asax.cs` file to apply gzip compression to each response when supported by the browser.

The solution was to exclude the addition of that filter when requests were made by AJAX (an update panel). This is easy to distinguish because the request contains a `X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true` header. This can be accomplished by wrapping the logic inside an if:

```
if (Request.Headers["X-MicrosoftAjax"] != "Delta=true")
{
    // Compression logic here
}
```

See also: https://forums.asp.net/t/1564697.aspx