# Fetch Mysql data from data base using C# not working

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL in where case a schoolid but when i use a response Response.Write(FatherFullName) for test to view nothin is showing up am not sure where am i going wrong

and provided i need one more help this question i have asked before but some one suggested me that my query has a threat of sql injunction so i replaced my query as my below expeted out put says that when iam fetching the data form data base using school id the if there the cell is not null or empty i need too add coma after each row data fetched

My DB

```
Father Name                School_id

1                             SC1
2                             SC1
3                             SC1
4                             SC1
```

Expected Output

```
1,2,3,4
```

the console log gives the error for fetch

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

```
                string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Logging"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FatherFullName  FROM euser_parent  WHERE SchoolId=@SchoolId", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolId", "FT001");
                        con.Open();
                        object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        if (o != null)
                        {

                            string FatherFullName = o.ToString();
                            Response.Write(FatherFullName); 

                        }

                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: On which line you get this exception? By the way, your `School_id` (I assume you don't have `SchoolId` column, just a typo) column does not have `FT001` string. That's why your `SELECT` statement would probably return empty result.

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks for replying again there is data in the data base am sure about it when i add `Response.Write(FatherFullName); ` at that time i get this error or else id dosent show's anything and the console also gives no error and in my previous question u asked me to change the code to prevent sql injuction i did and again i need ur help to add comma after row ur are the one who knows better then any now for now

Comment: Then what is the value of `FatherFullName` exactly? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: @SonerGönül and am not sure about my query it self the connection is correct and the where case is also correct the reader query i think is not correct and am fetching this data on button clik event

Comment: @SonerGönül `The thread '<No Name>' (0xb88) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4756] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4756] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: @SonerGönül Am sorry but my problem is am new to this the above is the debug code it think if it is not let me know and if you want i can share my screen to u

Comment: The error sounds like you're using an `UpdatePanel` and [modifying the response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554728/304683)? If that's the case test in a simple page (no update panels, etc.). Hth...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your next part to the following:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FatherFullName  FROM euser_parent  WHERE SchoolId=@SchoolId", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolId", "FT001");
                    MySqlDataReader msdr;
                    con.Open();
                    msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    string FatherFullName = "";
                    while (msdr.Read() && msdr.HasRows)
                         FatherFullName += ", " + msdr["fatherfullname"].ToString();
                    con.Close();
                    Response.Write(FatherFullName); // and cut the last comma from the string for display as you need
                }
```